# Accents appear separated from letter when pasting in google translate?

Tags: pdf, encoding, character-encoding, google-translate

I have a pdf file that I want to translate to English.
When I copy a text from the pdf file to Google translate ,the accents are separated from letters so Google does not recognize it.
Example:

or my be there is a better tool than Google translate to handle this and translate correctly

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: If you have Acrobat XI Pro, you may try to use the editing tool (Tools panel --> Content Editing pane --> Edit Text and Images), or export the document to Microsoft Word (Tools panel --> Content Editing pane --> Export File to… --> Microsoft Word…). Note that the latter requires Word installed, and works way better under Windows than under MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

That is the way, how the PDF is saved.

Try to use some software with OCR which is able to convert PDF format to text.